Why do we care if the likelihood function is tractable?
I'm learning (deep) generative models and I've seen many places where the difficulty is that the likelihood function (with some parameters defined by our model) is intractable, i.e., it involves complicated integration over some latent variables. However, if we want to do SGD for MLE, isn't it true that all we care about is the gradient of the likelihood function? Does the intractability of the likelihood necessarily imply the intractability of the gradient? Or do we care about the likelihood because, when doing SGD, we need to keep track of the objective to monitor convergence? After all, if we have learnt the parameters, then during infernence/sampling, we don't really need to compute the likelihood, because we can generate samples from the models directly (think about VAEs or diffusion models).

How would you find the gradient of the log likelihood function when the likelihood is intractable?

@Xi'an this does come up if $\log\mathcal{L}(y|\theta) = C + f(\theta)$ where $C$ cannot be computed.

@JohnMadden: Thank you, I agree with this case but I was wondering at a more involved scenario. Actually SGD is manageable even when using an unbiased estimator of $f(\theta)$.

It is possible to handle an "intractable" likelihood function through a range of methods.  You have mentioned some of the methods, but another common one is the EM algorithm.  As you point out, it is also possible to have a tractable gradient corresponding to an intractable likelihood function, which makes things easier than if the gradient is also intractable.  In principle, it is possible to compute and deal with a range of likelihood functions through various numerical methods.  The intractability of the likelihood function does not necessarily preclude computation of the gradiant, MLE, etc., though it might in some cases.
As to "why we care", I guess that really depends on how much an individual user finds it to be a pain in the arse to have to find and use (more complicated) numerical solution methods instead of (less complicated) analytical solution methods from standard calculus.  Ceteris paribus, a tractable likelihood is going to be much easier to deal with, so we will tend to care to some extent even if it is possible to solve in principle.  We tend to want to deal with simpler likelihood functions for illustrative purposes, but we can handle more complicated likelihood functions using special methods when needed.
